# Bind TextBox to Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, binding, bind

I'm trying to create multiple TabItem dynamiccally in each tab have a text box. Then I want to bind each text box to an dictionary index. For example

> TAB1     |       TAB2        |      TAB3
>
> TextBox1 |    TextBox2       |    TextBox3

Dictionary[TAB1] bind to TextBox1 ... etc

I'm doing this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Source = dic[id];
            binding.Path = ???

            TextBox stb = new TextBox()
            {
                Name = "tb" + id

            };
            stb.SetBinding(TextBox.Text, binding);
```

What should I put in the Path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this dynamically using view models:
1. Create a main view model to hold tabs.

```
 public class MainViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>();


    public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> Tabs
    {
        get { return this.tabs; }
    }
}
```

2. Create TabViewModel that will hold the dictionary and Header to display. In this example header is the key for dictionary but you can enhance it.

   public class TabViewModel
       {
           private readonly Dictionary dictionary;

   ```
       public TabViewModel(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
       {
           this.dictionary = dictionary;
       }

       public string Header { get; set; }
       public string TextValue {
           get { return this.dictionary[Header]; }
           set { this.dictionary[Header] = value; }}
   }
   ```
3. Create the tabcontrol using itemssource:

   ```
       <TabControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tabs}" >
           </TabControl>
   ```
4. assign the style to it

```html
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Header}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="sOfExamples:TabViewModel">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TextValue}"></TextBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
```

5. Assign the datacontext:

   MainViewModel mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
               Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary();
               dictionary.Add("Header1", "Header 1 text");
               dictionary.Add("Header2", "Header 2 text");

   ```
           mainViewModel.Tabs.Add(new TabViewModel(dictionary)
           {
               Header = "Header1"
           });
           mainViewModel.Tabs.Add(new TabViewModel(dictionary)
           {
               Header = "Header2"
           });

           this.DataContext = mainViewModel;
   ```

You can implement INotifyPropertyChanged on tabviewmodel if you want two way binding update.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I'll try that and give feedback

Answer (score 1):

A few things to notice here:

1. To be able to bind to it, the dictionary must be a public property:

   ```
   public Dictionary<string, string> dic { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   ```
2. To apply a binding to the text box' `Text` property, you need to refer to the dependency property itself rather than to its value:

   ```
   stb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
   ```
3. Finally, you're mixing up the binding's `Source` and `Path` properties: `binding.Path` is where the actual binding target belongs, while `Source` refers to the object that holds this target, in this case that's the current class (alternatively, it's possible to set the text box' `DataContext` property, which is then automatically applied as binding source to all of its bindings):

   ```
   binding.Source = this;
   binding.Path = new PropertyPath("dic[" + id "]");
   ```

However, the more elegant solution is binding the whole tab items, as described in Avneesh's answer.